# Posterior of a simple Bayes linear regression

Tags: regression, bayesian, notation

In the context of simple linear Bayesian regression, why or when is it appropriate to define the posterior as $p(\beta, \sigma^2|y)$ and not $p(\beta, \mu|y)$?

Comment: Is there are a particular context you've seen $p(\beta,\mu|y)$ in?

Comment: @SeanEaster no, just curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a bit rusty here, but let me take a crack at it.

Let's start by restating the simple regression model:

$$
\epsilon \sim Normal(0,\sigma^2)  \\
y = X\beta + \epsilon \\
\therefore y \sim Normal(X\beta, \sigma^2)
$$

Since $\mu = X\beta$, we get $\mu$ for free when we infer $\beta$ in the posterior. So it's actually a bit redundant to parameterize the posterior in terms of both $\mu$ and $\beta$.